# how to filter array using anonymous function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to write a function, preferably an anonymous one, that filters an array. It's hard to say in words, but it's like this:

```
f = @(x) { if (x > 1) x+1 }; 
a = [ 1, 2, 3];
f(a) % 
==> [ 1 3 4]
```

The key points I want is:

- want the function to receive a number
  or a string
- but when given an array,
  the function will apply itself to
  each element in the array and returns
  another array.

This is similar to the way the function log() works:

```
>> log(1) 
ans =
      0 
>> log([1,2,3])
ans =
      0    0.6931    1.0986
```

Thank you

Comment: @Martin08: What sort of string input do you expect the function to receive?

Comment: @b3: The strings will be in a cell array {'str1', 'str2' }. Thanks

Comment: @Martin08: What should the output of the function be when the input is `{'str1', 'str2'}`?

Comment: @b3: Thank you for your reply. The output would be a cell array, say {'STR1', 'STR2'}

Comment: @Martin08: I'm still trying to understand what you're after. Are you saying that these two criteria are true: `f([1 2 3]) = [1 3 4]` and `f({'str1', 'str2'}) = {'str1', 'str2'}`?

Comment: @b3: yes. In other words, what I am trying to do is analogous to what the "map" function (as in map/reduce) does in other languages.

Comment: @Martin08: I'm not familiar with the "map" function of other languages but I think I know what you mean. You should edit your question to explain more clearly the string input requirements. I'm stuck for answers on this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
f = @(x) x + (x > 1);
```